# Rendering of a vast grid in a Scrollview container without CATiledLayer?

Tags: ios, grid, scrollview, catiledlayer

I'm looking for any advice on ways to have a rather large scrollview (let's say 8192x8192) which is essentially a grid and it has subviews of about 5-100 buttons placed in it.

The  brute force approach runs out of memory as CALayer seems to be allocating a bitmap for the size of the scrollview's content (the memory issue is especially prominent when zooming is used)

I next added CATiledLayer to it, that's fixed the memory issue but there is a blurry effect on the grid as tiles are generated asynchronously and is still not ideal in that it's using a lot of memory for what is essentially a trivial 'draw some lines' task.

It seems like if I could somehow get control to draw my own grid via OpenGL each frame and tell UIKit not to create a bitmap buffer for the scrollview it would be perfect but not sure if this is feasible or even the right approach?

On Android I just took control of the entire drawing/zooming/panning but this seems vastly overkill on iOS which seems to offer most of this already?

Comment: There's a hint that adding subviews might be the way to do it (i.e. rects for each line of the grid) however I can't get that to work with the zoom yet...

Comment: There is a WWDC video from a few years back (2009?) I think it was called "Mastering Scroll Views" it described in detail how to do a tiled scroll view, which sounds like what you want if the asynchronicity of CATiledLayer is unacceptable. Maybe check it out and see if tha tmeets your needs.

Comment: Hi Carl, happy to mark this as the answer if you reply there.  I've opted for the CATiledLayer approach for the moment but will be revisiting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the WWDC 2009 video session 102: "Mastering iPhone Scroll Views" along with the ScrollViewSuite sample project from Apple. They explain how to do a tiled scroll view with different zoom levels, which sounds like it is what you need.

Comment: Any idea where one (with a developer account) can find these videos? The option to purchase seems to have disappeared.

Comment: I think you can get it [here](https://github.com/darcyliu/SampleCode/tree/master/ScrollViewSuite)